# Stream received but not showing in video element html for multi connection only

Tags: javascript, video, stream, webrtc

I am trying to write the code of SCREEN SHARING using WebRTC and socket.io using chrome extension for video conferencing.

I can connect with multi user in my web app.

I call sendStream() and set peerConn.addTrack(track, stream) after this 
peerConn.ontrack() called for every connection(client).

**I am getting the stream via getUserMedia()**

```
var sharedScreen = document.querySelector('#shared-screen');
sharedScreen.srcObject = remoteStream;
```

But I am stuck at a point:
When I done one to one connection then I got stream in peerConn.ontrack() and can show the stream in video element correctly

**but for multi connection(one to many) peerConn.ontrack() called and got stream but unable to show the stream in video element in html.
Stream received but not show in video element only in this case.**
(Could you please give a reason)*

```
function sendStream(stream) {
    console.log('UI: sendStream() ', stream);
    if (typeof stream !== 'undefined') {
        console.log('UI: creating peer connection in sendStream()');

        stream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
            // adding tracks
            peerConn.addTrack(track, stream);
        });

        console.log('isInitiator', isInitiator);
        if (isInitiator) {
            peerConn.createOffer(offerOptions).then(function(offer) {
                onLocalSessionCreated(offer);
            })
        }
    }else{
        alert("stream is:" + typeof(stream));
    }
}

/**************************************************************************** 
 * WebRTC peer connection and data channel
 ****************************************************************************/

var peerConn;
var dataChannel;

function signalingMessageCallback(message) {
    console.log('Client received message:', message);
    if (message.type === 'offer') {
        console.log('Got offer. Sending answer to peer.');
        peerConn.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message)).then(()=>{
            console.log("Answer creating");
            peerConn.createAnswer().then((answer) => {
                console.log("Answer creating > ",answer)
                onLocalSessionCreated(answer);
            }, logError)
        })
        .catch(logError);

    } else if (message.type === 'answer') {
        console.log('Got answer.');
        peerConn.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message), function(){}, logError);

    } else if (message.type === 'candidate') {
        console.log('Adding ICECandidate : peerConn.addIceCandidate()');
        peerConn.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate({candidate: message.candidate, sdpMLineIndex: message.label}));

    } else if (message === 'bye') {
        // TODO: cleanup RTC connection?
    }
}

function createPeerConnection(isInitiator, config) {
    console.log('Creating Peer connection as initiator?', isInitiator, 'config:', config);
    peerConn = new RTCPeerConnection(RTCConfiguration);

    // send any ice candidates to the other peer
    peerConn.onicecandidate = function (event) {
        console.log('onIceCandidate event:', event);
        if (event.candidate) {
            sendMessage({
                type: 'candidate',
                label: event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
                id: event.candidate.sdpMid,
                candidate: event.candidate.candidate
            });
        } else {
            console.log('End of candidates.');
        }
    };
    // called for each connection
    // stream received for each connection
    // but not showing in video element only for multi connection  
    // successfully showing for peer connection 
    peerConn.ontrack = function(event){
        console.log("stream added: peerConn.ontrack", event.streams[0], event.streams[0].id);
        let remoteStream = event.streams[0];
        sharedScreen.srcObject = remoteStream;
        var playPromise = sharedScreen.play();

        // playPromise won’t be defined.
        if (playPromise !== undefined) {
            playPromise.then(function() {
                // Automatic playback started!
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log("ontrack: error", error);
            });
        }
    }
}

function onLocalSessionCreated(desc) {
    console.log('local session created:', desc);
    peerConn.setLocalDescription(desc, function () {
        console.log('sending local desc:', peerConn.localDescription);
        sendMessage(peerConn.localDescription);
    }, logError);
}

function onDataChannelCreated(channel) {
    console.log('onDataChannelCreated:', channel);

    channel.onopen = function () {
        console.log('CHANNEL opened!!!');
    };

    channel.onmessage = (webrtcDetectedBrowser == 'firefox') ? 
        receiveDataFirefoxFactory() :
        receiveDataChromeFactory();
}

function receiveDataChromeFactory() {
    return function onmessage(event) {
        console.log("data received : channel.onmessage");
        debugger;
    }
}   

function receiveDataFirefoxFactory() {
    return function onmessage(event) {
        console.log("data received : channel.onmessage");
        debugger;
    }
}
```

And Could you please provide some good resource by I **can implement** video/screen sharing conferencing web app for industry level(can take load of 1000+ clients at a time with multiple sessions).
I have heard of SFU/MCU Janus WebRTC Server etc.

Help will be appreciated.
Happy Coding.

Comment: What is a "multi connection"? Are you using some library? If so, please tag the question accordingly. None of the code you're showing seems related to multiple connections. Also, just curious, why are you browser sniffing on data channels?

Comment: @jib Thanks for comment. Actually I am new to webrtc.

Comment: @jib
I need to make a video conferencing(multiple connections) web app.
I saw google https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p2HzZkd2A40 video. 
I need step wise tutorials/docs/wiki for implementing confrening web application same as google or any other community discussed.

Comment: Sorry, what you're asking is a ton or work, and too broad a question for this site. I recommend starting with tutorials on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API). Crawl, walk, run. Or use/purchase an existing solution.